# Failed to create the part's controls in RAD?

Tags: java, eclipse, web.xml, rad

Sometime my web.xml is not open properly, it shows `Failed to create the part's controls` error message when I try to open it. For the solution I have to clean and build, and restart my RAD(Rational Application Developer) multiple time, After a long process it works normally.
The whole error message is...

```
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "filter" must be declared.
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.loadDocument(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:81)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.doLoad(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:62)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:153)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:182)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1505)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1284)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:272)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.load(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:423)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:811)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.getResource(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:1064)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper.getOrCreateResource(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:380)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.EditModel.getResource(EditModel.java:685)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ArtifactEditModel.getResource(ArtifactEditModel.java:199)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.EditModel.getPrimaryResource(EditModel.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.EditModel.getPrimaryRootObject(EditModel.java:1500)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.ArtifactEdit.getContentModelRoot(ArtifactEdit.java:567)
at com.ibm.etools.web.ui.presentation.WebEditor.initializeRootModelObject(WebEditor.java:90)
at com.ibm.etools.emf.workbench.ui.presentation.ArtifactEditMultiPageEditorPart.initialize(ArtifactEditMultiPageEditorPart.java:324)
at com.ibm.etools.emf.workbench.ui.presentation.ArtifactEditMultiPageEditorPart.createPages(ArtifactEditMultiPageEditorPart.java:250)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:358)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:313)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:113)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:242)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:629)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:92)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:422)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:389)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:606)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3047)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(WorkbenchPage.java:2969)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2951)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2947)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2911)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2902)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:99)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:99)
at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.OpenActionGroup.runDefaultAction(OpenActionGroup.java:133)
at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.MainActionGroup.runDefaultAction(MainActionGroup.java:330)
at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator.handleOpen(ResourceNavigator.java:787)
at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator$6.open(ResourceNavigator.java:499)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "filter" must be declared.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.utilities.DOMUtilities.loadDocument(DOMUtilities.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.loadDocument(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:74)
    ... 122 more

Any other solution...?????

Comment: Could you add a copy of your web.xml file? looks like the XML parser is having problems to read it

Comment: @VictorSosa I have to override web.xml file many times and then restart RAD as well as. but it take a long period to resolve this prob.